# Is it possible to join two tables using a 'NOT LIKE '%%' condition?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need a query that compares a list of strings from one table with a list of strings in another table.

The pseudo code might be:

```
for each word in slang
 if not word.contains(animalName) {
  print animalName
 }
next slang
```

It doesn't have to be fast, it's not for production. I'm trying to debug something, and the result of the query is what I need to work with.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your pseudocode. Is `slang` an array of arrays? If not, how are you doing `if (animalName is not in word)` because that implies `word` is an array? I think you have a bug in your question.

Comment: I'm the poster child of "do in SQL Server everything you possibly can"...but this will be a whole lot easier with application code.

Comment: @Louis can you include an example, or more thoroughly explain what you're doing? Your question title doesn't seem to match your question body.

Comment: @RobertMartin sorry, I modified the pseudocode. It should make sense now.

Comment: @Louis nope, still doesn't. Do you mean to say `animalName` is an array and `word` is an item in the list `slang`? If so, you want to do `if not animalName contains word {`...

Comment: @Shark if it were clear what he's trying to do then I think it'd be very easy to do in SQL, but unfortunately it's not at all clear.

Comment: @RobertMartin you're right again. I fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All slang words that do not contain an animal name:

```
SELECT word 
FROM slang 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM animals 
  WHERE word LIKE '%'+ animalName + '%')
```

Answer (score 4):

So it sounds like you have a table `Slang`, and a table `Animals`, and you want all the combinations where `Slang` doesn't contain `Animal`. That's extremely simple

```
SELECT s.Word, a.AnimalName
FROM Slang s INNER JOIN Animal a 
ON s.Word NOT LIKE '%' + a.AnimalName + '%'
```

If you only want those words that aren't like any of the animal names, then you need to select the ones that *are* and then invert (but then how do you determine which 'word' goes with which 'animal name'?)

```
SELECT Word FROM Slang WHERE Word NOT IN 
(SELECT s.Word
FROM Slang s INNER JOIN Animal a 
ON s.Word LIKE '%' + a.AnimalName + '%') words
```

Comment: Thank you for figuring out what I wanted to say. I think this will work, but I can't confirm it just yet. I'm getting an error when I run it: `Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Japanese_CI_AI" and "Japanese_Unicode_CI_AI" in the like operation.`

Comment: You should be able to fix the collation in the like operation `s.Word COLLATE 'Japanese_CI_AI' LIKE ...`

Comment: +1 for figuring out the question and providing a working solution

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could pull the data into a .Net collection one for each table then use LNIQ to compare the them.

Answer (score 0):

Still trying to understand what you're looking for, but how about this:

```
SELECT term AS word FROM slang
EXCEPT
SELECT animalName AS word FROM allAnimalNames
```

Comment: There's no `MINUS` in TSQL - you probably mean `EXCEPT`?

Comment: Thank you. `MINUS` is in MySQL and I (wrongly) assumed it was the same in TSQL as well.

Comment: @RobertMartin: are you sure MySQL has `MINUS`? p.s. I don't think your answer will work.